# Usage of Dictionaries in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm an old, old programmer so I'm very used to abuse Arrays but I will need to start using dictionaries since they can dynamically expand and Arrays can't.

Now... I need to populate values for a solar system where each body in that solar system have perhaps about 20-30 different values.

My intention was to use a dictionary where each body has it's own unique Key and a value, such as...

```
Dictionary<int,string> BodyName = new Dictionary<int,string>()
Dictionary<int,int> BodySize = new Dictionary<int,int>()
Dictionary<int,int> BodyX = new Dictionary<int,int>()
Dictionary<int,int> BodyY = new Dictionary<int,int>()
Dictionary<int,int> BodyVelocity = new Dictionary<int,int>()
```

etc...

my question is what's the best way to go about to retrieve the values from all these dictionaries?
The key for each 'body" is the same in each dictionary. I know I can do this with lots of loops, but that seems quite wasteful on CPU cycles and that is a bad thing for me.

I also considered Dictionary,List but that has other issues I don't particularly like.

Comment: Erm, shouldn't you just be making a class called `Body` with 5 fields, and then have a `Dictionary<int,Body>`?

Comment: not sure why you wouldn't use a class for that.

Comment: Instead of making a dictionary for EACH property about a solar system body, make a class planet that holds all information about a solar system body, and make a dictionary of planets, for example. (Or list if you don't need lookup by key)

Comment: You're an old, old programmer and it doesn't RING ANY BELLS when you see `BodyName`, `BodySize`, `BodyX`...?? Why would you treat individual properties of the SAME OBJECT in OOP language as individual values?

Comment: I'm old as in NOT used to OOP as much... ;)

Answer (score 10):

Create a composite type, and use that.

Sticking with Dictionaries is suitable *if* the key is a *unique identifier* - a planet ID? a planet name? - that must be used to look up the data. Don't forget that iteration over dictionaries is non-deterministic.

```
Dictionary<int,PlanetaryBody> Bodies = new Dictionary<int,PlanetaryBody>()
```

On the other hand, a *sequence* is suitable if the planets are only iterated (or accessed by positional indices). In this case, using a [*List*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) often works well.

```
List<PlanetaryBody> Bodies = new List<PlanetaryBody>();
// Unlike arrays, Lists grows automatically! :D
Bodies.Add(new PlanetaryBody { .. });
```

(I very seldom choose an array over a List - it's better sometimes, but not often.)

---

The composite type (i.e. [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0b0thckt.aspx)) is used to group the different attributes into a larger concept or classification group:

```
class PlanetaryBody {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Mass { get; set; }
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: I have looked at classes as well... though I may be misstaken about classes have sort of bad performance issues. But other than that I should try using a class for the body and have the attributes set there.

Comment: @user2411504 There are **no performance issues using classes like this** (it will likely perform *better* than the many dictionary objects). Write clean code that does what is meant; simple (but just flexible enough), understandable, maintainable. Think how slow all my projects must be with hundreds of classes! - Just kidding, they are fast :D Go by the [97/3 rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize). This is not the 3%, so don't worry about performance.

Comment: Nice... I will start preparing for working with classes to store all the data.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a class for that.

```
public class Planet {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Size { get; set; }
  // and so on for each property of whatever type you need.
}
```

When you need a new Planet just new up:

```
var planet = new Planet();
planet.Name = "Saturn";
// again finish populating the properties.
```

To add it to a list:

```
var list = new List<Planet>();
list.Add(planet);
// adding the planet you created above.
```

Then look into manipulating lists and so on using LINQ

Comment: One thing I wonder about classes are memory usage, is that as efficient as a dictionary or are that pretty much the same. Bodies will be added in thousands or tens of thousands eventually.

Comment: depends. you should look into the underlying objects used in a dictionary. Where performance hit usually takes place is in the manipulation of the data. That and there are all sorts of collection types. One may be better than the other just depends again on what you're doing.

Comment: with all that said I would definitely start with classes from there you can populate into the collection of need and unit test for speed based on your criteria and see what fits best. Bottom line I don't think there is really one universal answer to this.

Comment: Most of the data is not used that often except for the position of the bodies that will be updated and accessed allot. So I might look into some special treatment of those specific values perhaps.

Comment: most of the associative collections use hashtable underneath. you might even go that route. In my tests hashtables are pretty darn snappy. Also if you're really serious about this, sounds as though you are (that's good btw), I would google some test batteries in c#.There's a class here on stack somewhere that does a benchmark. just google it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will do some testing and look into hashtables as well. Then, at least, I know where to start looking if there are performance issues in the end.